# Can I launch my Web Site project, and also have it use a Web Application project in the same solution?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, iis-express

I have an old legacy ASP.Net Web Sites project with a few hundred pages that I am responsible for maintaining.

I've been tasked with adding some new pages. Obviously, I'd rather add them in a slightly more modern format and want to do it with MVC.

While I theoretically *could* add the MVC to the Web Sites project, the solutions that I found online were janky -- in addition, in the near-ish future I'm hoping that I'll be able to convert the entire site to MVC a few pages at a time.

I also can't convert the entire Web Sites project to a Web Application project -- 3/4 of it is written in VB, and the rest in C#. When I tried to "Convert to Web Application", it only converted the 1/4 that were in C# -- I would have to manually rewrite the rest into C# to make them work.

As a result, I've added a separate project under the solution

Anyway~ on to the actual question.

Is there a way that I can debug both projects at once? I don't mean "Set them both as start-up projects!" because that opens them in separate windows with no inter-play. I need to be able to link to the Web App from the Web Pages and have the link work.

Obviously when this gets moved to production, we can play with some IIS stuff and make it work its magic, but in the meantime while I'm testing I'd like it to work as well.

Is there some way in Visual Studio that I can accomplish this? Or am I going to have to deploy it and do some IIS shenanigans to make it work?

Comment: Is this is web application or web site? Difference between app vs site are many, but relevant is web app site is fully re-compiled before deployment (web site app). Update to single web page code behind requires a full re-deploy. Most cases web site app requires your own hosted server. A web site is more flexible deploy wise and can be posted as a sub-site (and you can use low cost hosting). And you can update + re-deploy single pages (they compile on the fly).  Web site apps are better for things like custom authentication providers, but for your goals, more restrictive. No easy solution here

Comment: Sorry -- I may have been unclear in the question. 

The legacy site is a Web Site, and I'm looking to add a Web Application project (in order to begin migrating to MVC) to the solution, and am wondering if there's a way to debug them at the same URL so I can make sure the links between the sites work.

Comment: I don't believe you can. And if  you have two sites, then things like session(), and variable values that persist between pages, and the means by which values are passed between pages? I doubt this can work. I mean, if i have two seperate desktop programs, I can't really have one form from the first application now interact with the 2nd application and vice versa. I mean, if I could interact with other web pages, then when you come to my site, I would be looking to play with other pages - say like the one open that is doing your banking. So, I don't see a easy nor practical solution.

Comment: But, if this is a web site vs a web site application, then you can say introduce c# code at the same time as vb, and you can with greater ease say migrate from c# to vb. So  web site is somewhat more flexibility here - but not enough for your given goals.